# certificate and certificates tag merge request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

Can someone please merge the tag [certificates](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/certificates) to the tag [certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/certificate)?

There is likely many more tags that differ merely by plurality indication.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to merge all [tag:certificates] into [tag:certificate] - but can you clarify so that we're 100% sure?

Comment: yes please. Thats what I'd like.

Comment: Edited it for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)